# Error error : cannot find symbol class Picasso

Tags: java, android, gradle

Getting this error in picasso using the latest version of picasso that is 2.7... and using the right method also but still not able to resolve, please help

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserRecyclerAdapter extends 
  RecyclerView.Adapter<UserRecyclerAdapter.UserViewHolder> {

  public interface OnItemClickListener
  {
      void onItemClick(int position);
  }

OnItemClickListener listener;
Context context;
ArrayList<Movie> list;


public UserRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie> list , OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.listener=listener;
}

@Override
public UserRecyclerAdapter.UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_layout,parent,false);
    UserViewHolder holder=new UserViewHolder(itemView);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final UserRecyclerAdapter.UserViewHolder holder, int position) {

 Movie detail = list.get(position);

// holder.textview.setText(detail.getMovieName());


 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

         listener.onItemClick(holder.getAdapterPosition());
     }
 });
    Picasso.get().load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"+detail.getPosterPath()).into(holder.imageview);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return list.size();
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View itemView;
   // TextView textview;
    ImageView imageview;

    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
       // textview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        this.itemView = itemView;
        imageview = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes it is updated, pls have a look, it is like saying that 'error: cannot find symbol class Picasso'

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not added dependency in app.gradle file,

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Please check that. If already added, please try File -> Sync Project With Gradle Files.

Hope it will work.

Comment: already added and synced multiple times, it is succesfully build but when i try to run this it giveing error that - error: cannot find symbol class Picasso'

Comment: Have you tried File - >Invalidate Cache and Restart?

Answer (score 0):

**Try Invalidate Caches / Restart...** 
Got files/Invalidate Caches / Restart... >

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class is in the package folder and make sure you have the right package statement at the top of the class.